# I can not ping one gcp vm instance from another in the same network but in different regions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I noticed on GCP VM instance in the same network that you can't ping one from another using their instance names (hostnames) as taught in a pluralsight tutorial. But I can ping this other VM instance using both the internal and external IP addresses as expected from VMs in the same network.

Please note I have seen this [post](https://serverfault.com/q/939540/369307) but no luck. Perhaps there is a change in how VMs communicate.

Comment: 1) Did you configure custom hostnames when creating the instances? 2) Edit your question and add a hostname that does not work. There are two different formats.

Comment: Thank you so much I never new that one can set a custom hostname as the tutor just used the name of the instance. I see that the default format is `instance_name.zone.c.project_id.internal`. Please post an answer so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [@John Hanley](https://serverfault.com/users/437769/john-hanley) replied you can configure your own hostname when creating an instance.

For example you create an instance `vm1` with custom name `mycustomname.xxxx.xxx`. When you will be trying to ping the instance with custom name you stiull have to use `vm1` or the IP. This is due to the [GCP's Internal DNS](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/internal-dns#custom_hostnames) behavior:

> You can specify a custom hostname for a VM when you create it. Custom
> hostnames assigned in this way are not resolved by internal DNS. With
> custom hostnames, you still need to create a corresponding DNS record
> in the appropriate zone (for example, using Cloud DNS). See creating a
> VM instance with a custom hostname for more information.

You can find out even [more info about custom hostnames here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/custom-hostname-vm#limitations).

Generally internal DNS will resolve the name of the instances that are visible in the VM's list or running `gcloud compute instances list`. Even when you change the hostname at the OS level (`sudo hostname my_new_hostname`) it will only be visible to the VM's OS. No other VM will be able to ping this VM using new hostname.